# Facebook login issue with only Chrome while using DotNetOpenAuth 2.0 in mvc 3 application

Tags: google-chrome, dotnetopenauth

In my mvc3 application I have used DotNetOpenAuth for all providers, everything is working fine for all browsers except Chrome. Sometimes only I am getting below error message when I click on Facebook icon for login.

error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }

Facing this issue on few computers not on all. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it's actually a browser issue.  It's more likely a subtle difference in the URL to your web site between your different browser windows. Look for capitalization differences, or HTTP vs. HTTPS, trailing slashes, etc.  The URL used in your redirect_uri must be exactly as it appears in your app's Facebook registration page (within the boundaries set in the spec, which generally allow adding query string parameters IIRC).

If your site allows visits from multiple URLs (HTTP vs. HTTPS, different host names, etc.) you must take care to either redirect the user to a normalized URL prior to beginning the OAuth flow, or you must explicitly supply a normalized redirect_uri parameter value to DotNetOpenAuth so that the library doesn't pick up on the request URL by default.

Comment: Thanks @andrew.. it was url problem. in IE url pattern is different, so i was facing this issue.